# Building haskell package for n different version

Tags: haskell, nix

I'm trying to build [bytestring](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) and it fails with an error related to [quickcheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck). After a quick check (no pun intended), I found out that bytestring has a dependency on quickcheck with version `>= 2.4 && < 2.10` and by default `nix` build quickcheck version `2.10.1`.

After reading [this](https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix/tree/master/project1) now I know I can switch the quickcheck's version.

shell.nix:

```
{ compiler ? "default", doBenchmark ? false }:

let

config = { packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
             haskellPackages = pkgs.haskellPackages.override {
               overrides = haskellPackagesNew: haskellPackagesOld: rec {
                 myproject = haskellPackagesNew.callPackage ./default.nix { };
                 QuickCheck = haskellPackagesNew.callPackage ./quickcheck.nix { };
               };
             };
           };
         };

  pkgs = (import <nixpkgs> { inherit config; }).pkgs;

  f = import ./default.nix;

  haskellPackages = if compiler == "default"
                       then pkgs.haskellPackages
                       else pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler};

  variant = if doBenchmark then pkgs.haskell.lib.doBenchmark else pkgs.lib.id;

  drv = variant (haskellPackages.callPackage f { development = true;});

in

{myproject = if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then drv.env else drv;}
```

default.nix and quickcheck.nix is generated with `cabal2nix`.

Now it throws a different error that some of the package are missing its dependencies which is quickcheck with version `>=2.10`.

How to tell that only bytestring will use the custom version?

Edit: quickcheck's version switched to `2.9.2`

Comment: Note that in general, it may be a bad idea to have different versions in a dependency graph. It appears that GHC can deal with it reasonably well as long as the conflict is not part of the api's you're using. However, Nixpkgs refuses to create such dependency graphs, presumably because it causes more pain than help. Luckily test-only dependencies can be stripped out of the dependency graph, as they are only required for the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overriding a dependency on a single package

The problem is that the package set was created with the original quickcheck version. Globally overriding a much-used package like that is bound to cause problems.

Instead, you can override specific edges in the dependency graph like [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/be1461fc0ab29c45c69e7b2c2097c887750e4fe0/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/configuration-common.nix#L888):

```
myproject.overrideScope (self: super: {
    QuickCheck = haskellPackagesNew.callPackage ./quickcheck.nix { };
  });
```

---

### Composability

Your example can be improved further by using `haskellPackages.extend` instead of `overrides`. This will give freedom to further extend your package set after you have extended it before.

Another change you can make is to avoid `rec` recursive attribute sets in the definition of overrides and overlays. It is often best to use `self` instead. See this [blog post on flyingcircus.io](https://blog.flyingcircus.io/2017/11/07/nixos-the-dos-and-donts-of-nixpkgs-overlays/).

It's also a good idea to switch from `packageOverrides` to `overlays`.

These things may not cause issues right now, but will lead to surprises in larger projects, so it's better to avoid them in the first place.

### End result

I hope I got this right because I don't have the complete example.

```
{ compiler ? "default", doBenchmark ? false }:

let

  overlays = [(pkgs: super: {
             haskellPackages = super.haskellPackages.extend ( hself: hsuper: {
                 myproject = (hself.callPackage ./default.nix {}).overrideScope (pself: psuper: {
                     QuickCheck = pself.QuickCheck_2_9;
                   });
                 QuickCheck_2_9 = hself.callPackage ./quickcheck.nix { };
               };
             );
           };
         )];

  pkgs = (import <nixpkgs> { inherit overlays; }).pkgs;

  f = import ./default.nix;

  haskellPackages = if compiler == "default"
                       then pkgs.haskellPackages
                       else pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler};

  variant = if doBenchmark then pkgs.haskell.lib.doBenchmark else pkgs.lib.id;

  drv = variant (haskellPackages.callPackage f { development = true;});

in

{myproject = if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then drv.env else drv;}
```